# Google search company names and websites in Selenium pyhon

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, web-crawler

As a starting videographer I am trying to make a list of companies in a specific area.
So far I was able to get to the results with this code:

```
search_input = "hovenier Ridderkerk"
PATH = **location chromedriver**
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")

cookie_consent = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="L2AGLb"]').click()
time.sleep(0.5)
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/form/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/input')
time.sleep(0.5)
search.send_keys(search_input)
time.sleep(0.5)
search.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
time.sleep(0.5)
show_all = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="rso"]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[6]/div/g-more-link/a/div').click()
time.sleep(0.5)
```

however after this I am a bit stuck, it appears that the names and websites of these companies are in a lot of classes and I cant figure out over which element I should do an iteration to get all the company names and websites in the list.

*edit: I added the manual steps that I would like it to do.

1. go to google.com
2. search for 'hoveniers Ridderkerk' (garden companies)
3. show all results
4. make a list with all the company names and website addresses*

Can anyone guide me in the correct direction? perhaps also explaining how they know they should use that specific element, so next time I can do it myself?

Thank you!

Comment: One thing you must know is that even if you succeed in building a selenium code, it could get pretty unreliable in the very near future (which could even be tomorrow), because Google makes it hard and trickier for the bots.
Why don't you try google search api if you can

Comment: Update the question with the manual steps you are trying to automate.

Comment: this is most likely unreliable however I am as of yet not familiar with api's and it only needs the work for a couple of times to get all the results.